# irregular/varying batch size in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, batching

I have a tensorflow dataset and would like to batch it such that batches do *not* have the same size - something like examples being grouped in batches whose sizes are defined by a *vector* of values rather than a fixed value.

Is there a way to do it within tensorflow?

And for a network without fixed batch size, is feeding irregular batches going to be a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify - that means having a first batch of, say, 5 examples, a second batch of 10 examples, a third batch of 2 examples, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. model.fit() method [allows to pass to it a generator](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) which will generate randomly-sized batches.

```
x_train_batches = ... # some list of data batches of uneven length 
y_train_batches = ... # some list of targets of SAME lengths as x_train_batches

def train_gen(x_train_batches, y_train_batches):
    i = 0
    num_batches = len(x_train_batches)
    while True:
        yield (x_train_batches[i%num_batches], y_train_batches[i%num_batches])
        i += 1

model.fit(train_gen(x_train_batches, y_train_batches), epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=NUM_BATCHES)
```

Another, more elegant, way would be to subclass `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` and feed it to the model:

```
class UnevenSequence(keras.utils.Sequence):
      def __init__(self, x_batches, y_batches):
          # x_batches, y_batches are lists of uneven batches
          self.x, self.y = x_batches, y_batches
      def __len__(self):
          return len(self.x)
      def __getitem__(self, idx):
          batch_x = self.x[idx]
          batch_y = self.y[idx]
          return (batch_x, batch_y)

my_uneven_sequence = UnevenSequence(x_train_batches, y_train_batches)

model.fit(my_uneven_sequence, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Any suggestion on how to create x_train_batches given a tensorflow dataset with n examples and a list (or other iterator( that defines the size of each batch (e.g. bsize = [10, 2, 5, 6, 4]), which does not require looping through all the elements in the dataset? Are there any tf.data functions that could be of use here?

Comment: `numpy.split()` or `tf.split()` can do the job. you just need to convert batchsizes into split points (cumsum?).